# The cohomology of the Dirac operator $d+d^{*}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

Let  $(M,g))$  be a  Riemannian  manifold  with the Hodge dual operator $d^{*}$.

Is there a  name (and some  computation in some reference) for the cohomology of the complex of Harmonic forms with the boundary map $d+d^{*}$.

In the other word: Let $C^{p,q}$ be the space of  all  harmonic  $p+q$  forms on $M$. Assume  that $d:C^{p,q}\to  C^{p,q+1}$  be the vertical (upward) operator of differentiation  and  $d^{*}:C^{p,q}\to C^{p,q-1}$ be the horizontal (leftward) operator   Hodge  dual.

Let $T_{n}=\oplus_{q-p=n} C^{p,q}$. Then the Dirac operator $d+d^{*}:T_{n}\to T_{n+1}$ deefine  a complex. Its cohomology is the subject of this  question.

Comment: What's the difference between $C^{1,0}$ and $C^{0,1}$? You didn't make a distinction between them.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  Yes, you are right. But  I am trying to introduce  a  bicomplex(inspired by this concept in homological algebra).

Comment: Does that (somehow) correspond to the hypercohomology of the double complex?

Comment: Hold on, harmonic forms are in the kernel of both $d$ and $d^*$, so $d + d^*$ is the zero map.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese It is not true  a  harmonic form is  necesarilly  a  closed form. For instance is every Harmonic function necessarilly  a  constant function(on  a  non compact  manifold)?

Comment: Please consider the same for compact manifolds with boundary.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of the compact case.

Comment: (1) There must be a typo somewhere in your indices. You write that $d: C^{p,q} \to C^{p,q+1}$, $d^{\ast} : C^{p,q} \to C^{p, q-1}$, $T_n= \bigoplus_{q-p=n} C^{p,q}$ and $(d+d^{\ast}) : T_n \to T_{n+1}$. These aren't consistent: $d$ maps $T_n$ to $T_{n-1}$. (2) If you are just on a Riemannian manifold, with no complex structure, then there is no notion of a $(p,q)$-form, just a $k$-form.

Comment: The closest well formed question I can come up with is: Let $H^k$ be the harmonic $k$-forms and, for $r \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, let $A^r = \bigoplus_{k \equiv r \bmod 2} H^k$. Then $d+d^{\ast}$ maps $A^r \to A^{1-r}$, and the composition $A^r \to A^{1-r} \to A^r$ is $0$ because it is the Laplacian and we are talking about harmonic forms. Then it makes sense to ask for the cohomology of this complex. Is this what you mean?